# Continuous, well defined map in $l^p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I wonder if you could tell me how to handle problems like this one:

We are given a map from $\mathcal{l}^p$ to a field $\mathbb{K}$ and we are asked to determine whether it is well defined and continuous using the fact that a certain sequence is in $\mathcal{l}^p$

For example,

$$\varphi: \mathcal{l}^p \ni \{x_n\} \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{(n^5 +1)^{1/7}} \in \mathbb{K}$$
where $p \in [1, \frac{7}{2})$

or a similar one, only with $(n^6+1)^{\frac{1}{7}}$ in the denominator and $p \in [1,7)$

So the question is - how can I use the fact that $({\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} |x_n|^p})^{1/p}$ is convergent to determine convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{(n^5 +1)^{1/7}} $ ?

Thank you!

Edit: In the first example we get:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{(n^5 +1)^{1/7}} \le (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p)^{1/p} \cdot (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n^5 +1)^{q/7}}))^{1/q}, \ \ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}=1$$

So we need $\frac{5q}{7}>1$ in order for the second series to be convergent, and that leads to $q > \frac{7}{5}$

$\frac{1}{p} > 1- \frac{5}{7} = \frac{2}{7}$, and $p< \frac{7}{2}$

Is that correct?

Comment: Do you know Hölder's inequality?

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you check my solution? I added it to my post.

Comment: You should mention what $q$ is at an early stage, but with that done, it is correct. You will have no problems with the other one, I trust.

Comment: You mean $1/p + 1/q=1$? Yes, I forgot to write it down. No, I won't have problems with the other one. Thank you, again.

Comment: Yes. It's obvious that that's meant, but it should nevertheless be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: What do you mean by convergence in a general field $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: @T.A.E. , a complex series converges if and only if both the real and imaginary parts converge

Comment: @Spencer : So you're not considering a general field $\mathbb{K}$, but the field of complex numbers.

Comment: @T.A.E. Well, on our functional analysis classes we only considered fields of real and complex numbers. Does that make my solution incorrect?

Comment: @Spencer : It just means that you should specify $\mathbb{K}$ to be the field of real or complex numbers. For other fields, there may not be a way to define absolute value or convergence. Because functional analysis deals with convergence, norm, absolute value, then probably would never see any other field except $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. But linear algebra can be done over any field of scalars, and it's best to be specific.